# Dyncamically change 'MAX_DISTANCE_AT_ZOOM' and 'SHOULD_ANIMATE'

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-utils

I am using android-maps-utils for clustering markers in a google's map.

I need to offer users the posibility of changing the zoom level clustering and to switch on and off the clustering animation.

- Zoom level is managed inside NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.java, I was able to change it dynamically but it only works when doing it inside `onCreate()`, because if I change it after `mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(this, map, mClusterManager))` clustering becomes crazy. I need to be able to change it from inside `onResume()`.
- Animation is set inside DefaultClusterRenderer.java, I have tried many things but the only way I was able to change the `SHOULD_ANIMATE` variable was by fetching a shared preference directly inside that class, so making it posible to change that only by refreshing the activity. Again, I want to do it from inside `onResume()` or anyway that doens't involve refreshing the activity.